# Fill blank cell with value from previous cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which isn't functioning as I thought it would:

```
`Sub FillRow()
    Dim Name As String
    For Each c In Range("G1:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cells(c.Row, 1) > "" Then
       MsgBox ActiveCell.Address
            Name = Cells(c.Row, 1)
        Else
            Cells(c.Row, 1).Value = Name

        End If
    Next
End Sub`
```

Trying to get a blank cell in column G to be filled with the value above and left alone if it has a value. Nothing is happening - debugging seems to show the row isn't incrementing. I though this worked before

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the columns wrong. Try this:

```
Sub FillRow()
    Dim name As String
    Dim c As Excel.Range

    For Each c In Range("G1:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        If Len(CStr(Cells(c.Row, "G").Value2)) > 0 Then
            name = Cells(c.Row, "G")
        Else
            Cells(c.Row, "G").Value = name
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That works! Thanks. I thought for sure I had used the other code before.